# Ransack resultados de busqueda

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Soy nuevo en rails y tengo el problema que cuando hago submit me muestra todos, como si no buscara, me entrega todo lo de la BD. Mi codigo es:

Controller:

```
  class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
   def index
     @q = Company.ransack(params[:q])
     @people = @q.result
   end
  end
```

View:

```
 <%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :realname_cont, "Nombre" %>
    <%= f.search_field :realname_cont %>

   <%= f.submit %>
 <% end %>
```

La verdad me gustaria entender igual en parte el codigo, lo copie de la pagina de ransack. Espero alguien me pueda ayudar.

Saludos.

Comment: puedes mostrar el esquema de `Company`? Deberías tener un campo en la tabla `companies` que se llame `realname_cont`, por lo que entiendo de la documentacion

Comment: Lo que dice @inye no es correcto, tu campo debería llamarse `realname`. `_cont` es un predicado para decirle a ransack que **contenga** la información que estás pasando al input en el campo `realname`. [Aquí](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Basic-Searching) mas info sobre los predicados. ¿Puedes agregar a tu pregunta la información que te muestra en el log cuando realizas la consulta? Además de la vista donde estás mostrando la información.

Comment: Efectivamente el problema era la vista en la que mostraba la informacion. Puedo mostrar con otra vista ??

Saludos.

Comment: @MiguelAbdonHollstein claro que puedes

Comment: @AlterLagos seria mucho molestarte si me explicas como se hace?. Sorry pero soy super nuevo en esto..

Comment: @MiguelAbdonHollstein agrega el código que estás usando actualmente en la vista o el que consideres sea relevante para ayudarte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tanto tu Controlador como tu Formulario parece estar bien.
Asumo por tanto que tu problema está en la parte del código que no estás mostrando. En el listado de las compañías. Para que sea correcto deberías estar haciendo:

```
<%= @people.each do |person| %> ### NO <%= @q.each do |person| %>
```

Se que al estar asumiendo la parte que no veo debería comentar, pero lamentablemente no tengo los créditos suficientes.

EXPLICACIÓN DEL CÓDIGO:
Tu Controlador:
La primera variable (@q) es en la que ransack devuelve los resultados. Podrías agregar antes del scope que te provee ransack, cualquier scope tuyo que quieras limitar. Por ejemplo:

```
@q = Company.where(status: "active").ransack(params[:q])
```

La segunda variable (@people) es en la que tiene los resultados. Hasta donde se no es una relación de ActiveRecords sino una instancia de Ransack que guarda tus resultados (ahora si una relación de ActiveRecrods) en el método "results". Si quisieras agregar paginación a tus resultados, tendrías que aplicarla a este segunda colección y no a la primera.

Tu vista: El formulario.
Ransack genera automaticamente una serie de helpers y métodos en tus objetos. Por ejemplo el que estás usando en tu ejemplo. Asume que tienes un campo de tu BBDD llamado "realname", ransack agrega automáticamente el método realname_cont para verificar si esa columna "contiene". Podrías usar realname_eq si quieres que el termino buscado se exactamente igual "equal" al campo.

Espero haber ayudado. Saludos